# sort linked list twice in c language

Tags: c, linked-list

I have a problem with sorting my linked list. I want to sort it twice, like this:

Input

```
char cl; int time; int lng;
```

```
A 2 2

B 2 1

C 0 2

D 0 1
```

I want the output to look like this :

```
C 0 1

D 0 2

B 2 1 

A 2 2
```

As you can see the output that I want is sorted by the second and the third column. I was only able to sort by the second column using this code.

```c
void sort (const node *n)
{
    node *list,*pass;
list = n;
for (; list->next != NULL; list = list->next)
{  for (pass=list->next; pass!=NULL; pass=pass->next)
    if (list->time < pass->time)
    {   swap(list, pass);

    }
 }
}
```

Comment: The formal term is _Radix Sort_, but the short version is that you sort repeatedly, from least-significant key to most-significant key, provided you have a stable sort (yours is).

Comment: Or you can add a condition like after your `if`, to check that if `time` is equal, you should sort by the other element.

Comment: @JohnC i have looked everywhere but i couldn't find it for two variables in lined list , any help please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

John C gives you a nice hint (check from least-significant key to most-significant key):

```
int comp(const void *pa, const void *pb)
{
    const node *a = (const node *)pa;
    const node *b = (const node *)pb;

    return (a->lng < b->lng) ? 1 :
           (a->time < b->time) ? 1 :
           (a->cl < b->cl) ? 1 : 0;
}

void sort(const node *n, int (*comp)(const void *, const void *))
{
    node *list, *pass;

    list = n;
    for (; list->next != NULL; list = list->next) {
        for (pass=list->next; pass!=NULL; pass=pass->next) {
            if (comp(list, pass)) {
                swap(list, pass);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Call it using:

```
sort(node, comp);
```